# How to upload content to WildFly welcome-content via jboss-cli-client?

Tags: jenkins, wildfly, continuous-deployment

I am using Jenkins builder and have WildFly server. How do I upload content to WildFly welcome-content folder via jboss-cli-client.jar, that I am using for uploading deployments?

I can enter the deploy command to Jenkins batch, now I would like to upload the welcome-content. I searched command, but did not find any pointers what it could be.

Comment: The `welcome-content` is just a directory. There is no way to upload content into some directory. What is it you want in there?

Comment: some static content where I would like to have updates in same phase that the app changes. Basically a html page with version info and such. The issue is that I use Jenkins to publish to machine, where I have limited access and thus would like to avoid logging in to change such trivial things.

Comment: So ftp or similar should be used to copy those contents?

Comment: Yes. You'd need a way to copy files to the file system. The `jboss-cli-client` is really for executing management commands/operations. There are operations for deployments, but not static content.